# google map not working when .apk is installed in Device

Tags: java, android, dictionary, genymotion

I have created a project as per instructions at http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435 which was instructed at some other query.

It was not working in Android Virtual Device which came with the eclipse I downloaded. I was getting some error regarding GPU V2 was required. So I configured Genymotion virtual device with Eclipse and its working very smoothly.

After that I exported the project and created .apk file. Then I unistalled the app from the virtual device and re-installed the .apk file which was extracted. On doing that the map is not getting displayed. The same thing is occuring when the file is installed in a real device (Samsung Note II).

Please help!!

Comment: check this  https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/161869/google-maps-v2-for-android-not-working-on-built-apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

One general thing is , If your map is not getting displayed then your Key is wrong .

You should generate a separate key for running from eclipse using `debug.keystore` and separate key for .apk files using `yourapp.keystore` that you generate while taking .apk file .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be debug/production keystore issue. 
Just follow this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro